# How to convert RGBA array into Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap

I'm finding a way to convert RGBA bitmap to `Mat` in OpenCV. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27585652/5126079), but the output image had wrong color and was upside-down.

I use a struct array to store the bitmap.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char r,g,b,a;
} BITMAP;
BITMAP* input = (BITMAP*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(BITMAP));
...
Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC4, input);
```

Does anyone know any convenient method to convert Bitmap to Mat in OpenCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV's cv::Mat uses row major ordering (increment first along channels, then along columns, then along rows).  So, the pixel at (0, 0) is the most top-left pixel in the image.  If your BITMAP had (0, 0) as the bottom-left, then the image would appear upside down.  Typically, OpenCV prefers BGRA ordering of the channels.  The reordering of the channels will mess up the coloring.

Comment: Thank you! I remapped the pixels and the channels as your said. It finally works!